# php,mysql - query data from mysql table and display results using for each

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I first query specific columns from a mysql table and want to echo them all using foreach() in php. 
Here is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, roll_no, email, title, abstract, supervisor, sub_date
        FROM student_data";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$array = $result->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($array as $x => $value)
{
    echo $array["id"] . " " . $array["name"] . " " . $array["roll_no"] . " " . $array["title"] . " " . $array["supervisor"] . " " . $array["sub_date"] ."<br><br>";
}
```

It simply keeps repeating the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main missunderstanding is that `$array = $result->fetch_assoc();` returns only one result. To get the second one you should call `$result->fetch_assoc()` once again. 
So you should iterate in this way

```
while ($array = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $array["id"] . " " . $array["name"] . " " . $array["roll_no"] . " " . $array["title"] . " " . $array["supervisor"] . " " . $array["sub_date"] ."<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only looping through the elements in the first result set. You need to iterate through the entire result set:

```
while($array= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $array["id"] . " " . $array["name"] . " " . $array["roll_no"] . " " . $array["title"] . " " . $array["supervisor"] . " " . $array["sub_date"] ."<br><br>";
}
```